# たform+こと が/は(particle) ありますか?

Tags: grammar, は-and-が

Continuation from my other question:
if we were asking as a question, 'みたことがありますか。' Can we use the question はparticle interchangeably? Or which to use under which circumstances? Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify your question please? It isn't clear what you are asking at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question is clear enough, although there is no specific context.

I don't know whether all the questions about は/が should be regarded as "duplicated questions." If so, I had better not write this. But anyway, I will try to answer it.

Now I think that the both of は and が are almost completely interchangeable and have the same meaning, in general.

The choice depends on each concrete context. It depends on other grammatical rules.

For example:

> 日本に行ったことはありますか？ a
>
> 日本に行ったことがありますか？ b

a and b are completely the same and it depends only on the speaker's preference.

> あなた**は**日本に行ったこと**は**ありますか?　c
>
> あなた**は**日本に行ったこと**が**ありますか?　d

I believe not a few Japanese would choose d, because c includes the double "は" s which seem less natural to native-Japanese speakers' ears.

Hope this helps!

Comment: C is not less natural to me.